# Enabling “Showcase” mode in Shiny/RCloud

Tags: r, shiny, rcloud

I am trying to enable showcase mode for my shiny app and having trouble understanding how to do that.

https://github.com/att/rcloud.shiny/blob/master/R/shiny-overrides.R

This override code shows how to enable it, but having trouble to get it working.

```
# Showcase mode is disabled by default; it must be explicitly enabled in
  # either the DESCRIPTION file for directory-based apps, or via
  # the display.mode parameter. The latter takes precedence.
  shiny:::setShowcaseDefault(0)
```

Comment: I've had reports that this feature doesn't work in rcloud.shiny. I will have the team look at it!

Comment: [Here's the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/att/rcloud.shiny/issues/23) if you want to follow it. We're planning another release of RCloud at the end of the month.

Comment: Showcase mode is supported by rcloud.shiny 0.5.2, which will be released with RCloud 1.9.1 in early February.

Comment: Has there been any updates on the RCloud 1.9.1 update?

Comment: The software has been released and is deployed in Research. We're waiting for it to be deployed in the rest of the company and on rcloud.social

Comment: Has there been any development on the push for RCloud 1.9.1 update?

Comment: This would be a better question for internal Stack - could you please ask a new question there?